# Should I acronymize "Health, Safety, and Environment" as "HSE" or "SHE"?

Tags: abbreviations, word-usage

Which abbreviation is most used for "Health, Safety and Environment"? I keep seeing different abbreviations, and a quick search on Google shows that they are all used widely. But does anyone actually know if there is one "correct" abbreviation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Environmental Health and Safety vs Environmental, Health, and Safety guidelines](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16272/environmental-health-and-safety-vs-environmental-health-and-safety-guidelines)

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly be considered a duplicate of that question, @F'x.

Comment: I was wondering about the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this, it's [HSE](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/norwegian_to_english/construction_civil_engineering/2795872-hms_helse_milj%C3%B8_og_sikkerhet.html) :)

> While this is not a definitive answer
>   (there isn't one!), it certainly is
>   established in the UK and Norway, too.
>   In the UK the more informal term is
>   "health and safety", just as
>   Norwegians talk about "helse og
>   miljø".

but also check [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_ics_browse.htm?ICS1=13) - it's EHS :)

Comment: Yes, In Norwegian it is HMS, which would be HES in English. I have also seen that used. But if we look away from Norwegian translations of it completely - what is used in English?

Comment: @masarah if you look at the link the vote went 5+7 for HSE; 5-1 for EHS and 5-1 for SHE; there's also a mention of how it is used in German, Spanish, French and Italian :)

Comment: Note that in the UK. HSE is the Health and Safety Executive, in charge of safety legislation, equivalent to OSHA in the USA.

Comment: @mgb And in Ireland, the HSE is the Health Service Executive, roughly equivalent to your NHS.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear that there is a "correct" version. There is no official organization for Environment, Health and Safety. [Wikipedia lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment,_Health_and_Safety) both as usable and includes HES to boot:

> Environment, Health and Safety (EHS) – also Safety, Health and Environment (SHE) or HES – is often used as the name of a department in corporations and government agencies.

If you are referring to a *specific* department, you should obviously use their name. If you are creating a new department, I suggest looking up your local city or state department to see if they offer a specific form. I prefer EHS because it doesn't collide with the word "she" while searching which made it a little hard to search for usage.

Comment: Thank you. I'm mostly asking because I keep meeting it in translation work, so I just wanted to know if there was something that was definitely "wrong".

Comment: @masa: Not as far as I can tell. In the case of translations I would try to keep the order as close to the original as possible _or_ ask your office/superior if they have a preference for the term. If the original terms are just too far apart, pick one for your use and stick with it until you have a good reason to change. :)

Comment: MrHen: of course. Just wanted a second opinion before I picked one :)

Answer (score 0):

EHS is the most common, though it's expanded differently in different cases -- Environment, Health, and Safety; Environmental Health & Safety; Environmental, Health, Safety (which, counterintuitively, refer to the same sorts of things).

Comment: I have actually never come across it used as EHS. Interesting...

Comment: Almost every research university in the US has such a department, and 80+% of them are called EHS.  I can't speak for the UK or other countries here, that's outside my professional experience.

Comment: I'm less sure of what the trends are in industry.  "Ignoring the problem" is probably more common than EHS.